# How to use Google Analytics Reporting to Get the Average Session for a given date range?

Tags: .net, api, google-analytics

I'm using .NET and I've installed the NuGet package of the google analytics:

```
 Install-Package Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4
```

The APIs are here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session

I'd need to use the below API:

```
ga:avgSessionDuration
```

I've created an API Key for Credentials and know my ViewId and ClientId too.

How to use the .NET client library to access this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing:

1 Create a Google Service Account

2 Give permissions on your Analytics account to allow the Google Service Account to view the data

3 Set up authentication http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/

4 Play around here to find out which metrics/dimensions you need to query and also data ranges https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

5 Initialize the AnalyticsService mentioned in step 3

6 Generate a request {YourAnalyticsService}.Data.Ga.Get("ga:{viewid}", {start_date},{end_date}, ga:{metric});

Comment: Where do I find the client secret? couldn't find it from the console?